# ValueError: repeats may not contain negative values

Tags: python, pandas

I have an dataset which looks like the following:

[image]

I want to repeat the columns from `id` to `document` and delete the rowa where `ShortCode` is empty.

To repeat the dataframe I tried the following:

```
df = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df.id)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

But it gives the following error

> ValueError: repeats may not contain negative values.

How can I do that ?

The sample dataset:

```
     id                                   warehouse          material_vendor  \
0  21.0  Yantraksh Logistics Private limited_GGNPC1  Yana Packagings Pvt Ltd   
1   NaN                                         NaN                      NaN   
2   NaN                                         NaN                      NaN   
3   NaN                                         NaN                      NaN   
4   NaN                                         NaN                      NaN   
5  22.0  Yantraksh Logistics Private limited_GGNPC1  Yana Packagings Pvt Ltd   
6   NaN                                         NaN                      NaN   
7  23.0  Yantraksh Logistics Private limited_GGNPC1  Yana Packagings Pvt Ltd   
8   NaN                                         NaN                      NaN
```

Expected output:

[image]

Red ones should be deleted as the `ShortCode` is empty

Comment: can you post the expected output

Comment: @deadshot Please have a look now

Comment: Does df.id contains a negative value?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can much more easily achieve this with `ffill()` instead of `reindex` and `repeat` making the error `ValueError: repeats may not contain negative values` irrelevant:

```
df['ShortCode'] = df['ShortCode'].fillna('remove') #the reason why I do this to more easily use ffill() on the entire dataframe, but I want to save the "remove" value, so I can remove later
df = df.ffill()
df[df['ShortCode'] != 'remove']

Out[1]:
    id                                       warehouse  material_vendor  .....  ShortCode
1   21.0    Yantraksh Logistics Private limited_GGNPC1  Yana Packagings Pvt Ltd Separator
2   21.0    Yantraksh Logistics Private limited_GGNPC1  Yana Packagings Pvt Ltd INSERT
3   21.0    Yantraksh Logistics Private limited_GGNPC1  Yana Packagings Pvt Ltd INSERT
4   21.0    Yantraksh Logistics Private limited_GGNPC1  Yana Packagings Pvt Ltd INSERT
6   22.0    Yantraksh Logistics Private limited_GGNPC1  Yana Packagings Pvt Ltd INSERT
8   23.0    Yantraksh Logistics Private limited_GGNPC1  Yana Packagings Pvt Ltd INSERT
```